# dynamically loading components on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, react-hooks

I have some components that I import on my entry file App.tsx using this library: https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components my code looks something like:

I am receiving an error that says:

> loadable.esm.js:272 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically
>   imported module:
>   http://localhost:3000/static/js/components/header/Header

Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong! Do I need to enable something or change, just so you know i am using CRA!

UPDATE: I googled it abit and it seems like I need to change smth on webpack or install some plugin for it, but I dont maintain webpack, cra is kinda responsible mantaining webpack.

Comment: is the path correct

Comment: which path? @ShubhamKhatri, if you are talking about Header component yes its correct path

Comment: i tried to log out import output and it logs [[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a demo reproducing your issue on codesandbox

Comment: i dont think its worth it, it kinda seems obvious that CRA can't support such thing!